# How can i Split Menu Bar in two lines

Tags: css

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8Uu/1/

I have got a Menu as shown in the fiddle 
Right now the Menu is being shown under one line .

How can i make that display in two lines ??

Means

```
ONE TWO THREE (First Line )
FOUR FIVE SIX (In second line )
```

Could anybody please let me know how to do this ??

The above CSS was given two me

I am using this to append data dynamically to the menu

```
function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
var categoryArr = categories;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr[0].length; i++) {
        if (categoryArr[i] != undefined) {
  $("#swiper-wrapper").append('<li id= "' + categoryArr[i] + '" class="swiper-slide">' + categoryArr[i] + '</li>');
        }
    }
}




 <section class="menuWrap">
      <div class="menuInner">
         <div class="swiper-container">
            <ul id="swiper-wrapper" class="swiper-wrapper"> 
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

Please let me know how can i make Menu Bar dispay in two lines ??

Updated answer

```
 function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
var categoryArr = categories;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr[0].length; i++) {
        if (categoryArr[i] != undefined) {
            if(i==4)
            {
$("#swiper-wrapper").append('</ul><ul>');
            }
  $("#swiper-wrapper").append('<li id= "' + categoryArr[i] + '" class="swiper-slide">' + categoryArr[i] + '</li>');
        }
    }
}
```

The output HTML that function creates is

```
<ul id="swiper-wrapper" class="swiper-wrapper" style="width: 0px; height: 30px;">
   <li id="Chips &amp; Chocolates" class="swiper-slide">Chips &amp; Chocolates</li>
   <li id="Ice creams" class="swiper-slide">Ice creams</li>
   <li id="Popcorn" class="swiper-slide">Popcorn</li>
   <li id="Snacks &amp; Corn" class="swiper-slide">Snacks &amp; Corn</li>
   <li id="Soft Drinks" class="swiper-slide">Soft Drinks</li>
   <li id="Tea &amp; Coffee" class="swiper-slide">Tea &amp; Coffee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you just used something with display:inline-block instead of <li>'s, and put a <br> there, it would wrap just like text does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule set:

```
.menuWrap .menuInner ul li:nth-child(4) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: +1, and throw a margin on the bottom of the the `li`s

Comment: if(i==4)
  {
$( ".menuWrap .menuInner ul li:nth-child(4)" ).css( {" clear: left" });

} , but this isnt refleclting , could you plz tell me why ?

Comment: Sure.  Your .css() function object syntax is off.  Here's the correct one: $( ".menuWrap .menuInner ul li:nth-child(4)" ).css({
    "clear": "left"   
});

Comment: And Josh KG is right - formatting could use a facelift.  And, apply `list-style-type: none` to get rid of bullets.  Better yet, it is almost always a good practice to use a reset css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the menu into two different `<ul>`. If you add `</ul><ul>` after the `Three</li>`, it will split it into two rows. You'll need to adjust the css some to fix the heights then.

Comment: I followed your answer and tried it this way  please see te updated answer part in  my question , but its not coming in two lines .

Comment: Can you copy the outputed HTML that that function creates?

Comment: I have copied the output HTML of this function

Comment: Since its a stylized `ul` you will want to change it from `</ul><ul>` to `</ul><ul id="swiper-wrapper" class="swiper-wrapper" style="width: 0px; height: 30px;">` 

But I don't see why it isn't working. Are you using any caching system that may need to be flushed or updated? Also, instead of using `i==4`, you should think about using `if (i==(i/2) or i==(i+1)/2)`, so it will still cut halfway even if the menu number changes, just because the dynamically generated menus could change.